# list of android market to publish app

Tags: android

**hello friends**,

I need a publish my app in `different-different` market but not in `https://market.android.com/`. so    simply I need a list of that can any one help me?

**Thanks

nik**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websites like http://www.appbrain.com, http://www.androidpit.com , http://www.androidblip.com/, are market aggregators. They scrape the market for information on new apps (ratings, comments, etc). and put them on a website that is searchable and sortable. You don't have to do anything special to get your applications on these websites, they will eventually find your app and add it to their listing.

Android Market is the official market that everyone can get to. The problem is, there are still some countries that cannot purchase apps in the Android Market. So you would turn to alternative markets to try and reach your business into those places. A short list would include:

```
 1. Google Android Market
 2. SlideMe
 3. AndAppStore
 4. Handango
 5. AndroidGear
 6. Phoload
 7. Mobihand
 8. AppsLib
 9. Insyde Market
10. NetDragon
11. KUQU
12. Noverca
13. GetJar
```

Plainly Copied from https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/where-to-upload-android-application